# What is the purpose of the commented-out sun.security.ec.SunEC provider in java-7-openjdk?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, java, elliptic-curve

I have a stock installation of openjdk 7u21-2.3.9-5 as included with Linux Mint Debian Edition (jessie/sid) 201403.

I'm trying to write java code to establish an SSL/TLS connection mutually-authenticated using Elliptic Curve keys.  It's not working.

**Update:** *Since originally posting this question, I have since succeeded in establishing a secure connection by using the secp256r1 curve (rather than secp256k1) for both the server and client keys.  However I am leaving this question mostly as I originally wrote it since I still am interested in the answer to the question.  In particular I note that [the security of the secp256r1 curve has been questioned](http://www.linuxadvocates.com/2013/09/is-openssls-cryptography-broken.html).*

In searching the internet for help my attention was called to the second-to-last provider listed in my `java.security` file:

```
#security.provider.9=sun.security.ec.SunEC
```

Why is this here?  Why is it commented out?

I have tried using SSL (TLS) client keys based on both the `secp256k1` and `secp256r1` curves.  I've also tried adding bouncycastle as a provider.  With the server certificate using `secp256k1` I cannot establish a connection, even with the bouncycastle provider available; on the other hand, if the server and client keys are both based on the `secp256r1` curve then I can establish a secure connection.

So far, my understanding is that there is a SunEC cryptographic provider that supports all EC curves but is not included with OpenJDK, that if I could find and install the proper java `jar` file and binary shared binary library then I could use that provider, but also that there is some incompatibility between that and the included `rt.jar` file.

Furthermore, I understand that the SunPKCS11 provider, which is included with OpenJDK, handles a subset of EC curves, including `secp256r1`, but not `secp256k1`.  If bouncycastle is available then it seems to kicks in when trying to use the `secp256k1` curve for the client key, but not for the server key.  I have little confidence in the accuracy of my understanding because it's based on information from thread comments and other non-authoritative sources.

I am additionally confused by the fact that invoking the method `sun.security.ec.NamedCurve.getECParameterSpec("secp256k1")` returns an EC Parameter Specification, indicating that my JDK *does* know about that curve.  So I'm confused why it cannot handle SSL certificates using keys that are based on that curve.

At this point I am able to establish a secure connection, but only with certain EC curves.  I would like to have the option of using more curves, and in general am very curious of why there is a commented-out provider specified in the distributed `java.security` file.  That's my question: why is it there; how can I use it?